# Javascript: Adding comma to number

Tags: javascript, numbers, numeric

When the number reaches 1000 it adds the comma and becomes like so 1,000 although once it implements the ',' it then resets back to 12 where it should carry on.

Here is my jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m9cey/3/

```
var millisecs = 1000;
setInterval(function() {
    var $badge = $('#badge');
    var num = parseInt($badge.text())+11;
    $badge.text(num.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ","));
}, millisecs);
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: I would suggest separating the value and the output. That way you're not trying to parse text to a number and then converting it back. Store the value as data, and then output the stringified value to the DOM. http://jsfiddle.net/m9cey/10/

Comment: Why the `+ 11`?  What is that supposed to achieve?

Comment: Working as expected.  `parseInt` will parse up to -- BUT NOT INCLUDING -- the comma.  The [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) for `parseInt` will help you a lot.

Comment: Thanks for your input guys! The answer below helped!

Comment: I bet no one has ever had this question before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `,` in the value is causing parseInt to stop at it. So `parseInt('1,xxx')` will give you 1 then add eleven to it you get 12 .

Easiest solution remove the comma before parseInt

```
var num = parseInt($badge.text().replace(',', ''))+11;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/m9cey/9/

Comment: Thanks Musa this works perfect. Cheers for the fast response. Will tick asap.

Comment: If your numbers can get really big you need to replace globally

Comment: Going on from this topic, i'm trying to make it so that it goes up $11.43 per second. So ideally, I need to remove the .00 and include the 43 somehow?  

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 2):

Just posting my comment as an answer: http://jsfiddle.net/m9cey/10/

```
<span id="badge" data-value="900">900</span>

setInterval(function() {
    var $badge = $('#badge'),
        num = parseFloat($badge.data('value'));

    num += 11;

    $badge
        .data('value', num)
        .text(num.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ","));
}, millisecs);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you heard of [numerals.js?](http://numeraljs.com/)

```
var string = numeral(1000).format('0,0');
// '1,000'
```

Comment: Yup I had looked at that but then got lead onto something else!. Thanks though!